# Delete values and flatten DataArrays of xarray Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is it possible to delete values of DataArrays contained in an xarray Dataset such that `xr_dataset` would be transformed into `xr_flat` in the example code below?

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
n = np.nan

a = np.array([[n,n,1],
              [1,2,2],
              [2,n,n]], dtype='float32')
b = np.random.rand(3,3)
xr_dataset = xr.Dataset({'a': xr.DataArray(a, dims=['x', 'y']),
                         'b': xr.DataArray(b, dims=['x', 'y'])})

a_flat = a[np.isfinite(a)]
b_flat = b[np.isfinite(a)]

xr_flat = xr.Dataset({'a': xr.DataArray(a_flat),
                      'b': xr.DataArray(b_flat)})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using xarray's `stack` and `where` methods. To be consistent with your example, I've also dropped the x/y coordinates but that isn't strictly required. The key pieces are:

1. Use stack to flatten `x`/`y` dims into `dim_0`
2. Use `where` with `drop=True` to mask and select only the finite elements

Here's an example, starting where you left off...

```
In [2]: ds_stack = xr_dataset.stack(dim_0=('x', 'y'))

In [3]: ds_stack = ds_stack.reset_index('dim_0').drop(['x', 'y'])

In [4]: ds_stack.where(np.isfinite(ds_stack['a']), drop=True)
Out[4]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_0: 5)
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Data variables:
    a        (dim_0) float32 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
    b        (dim_0) float64 0.8642 0.05446 0.3728 0.7797 0.9501

In [5]: xr_flat
Out[5]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_0: 5)
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Data variables:
    a        (dim_0) float32 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
    b        (dim_0) float64 0.8642 0.05446 0.3728 0.7797 0.9501
```